# JSDoc: @type for nested function

Tags: javascript, intellij-idea, jsdoc

I have a `factory` function that defines and returns other function - `myFunc`. I want to document my working variables with JSDocs:

```js
function factory() {
    function myFunc(param) {
        console.log(`Hello ${param}!`);
    }

    return myFunc;
}

/** @type {factory} */
const fact = factory;
/** @type {???} */
const fn = fact();
fn('world');
```

I can document `factory` function:

```js
/** @type {factory} */
const fact = factory;
```

but my IDE (IDEA PhpStorm) cannot resolve inner function the same way:

```js
/** @type {myFunc} */
const fn = factory();
```

I cannot use Ctrl+click navigation in this case. Does any method exist to address inner function? Smth. like `factory#myFunc`:

```js
/** @type {factory#myFunc} */
const fn = factory();
```

Answer (score 0):

It is possible with `@exports` [directive](https://jsdoc.app/tags-exports.html) on nested function:

```js
function factory() {
    /** @exports myFunc */
    function myFunc(param) {
        console.log(`Hello ${param}!`);
    }
    return myFunc;
}

/** @type {factory} */
const fact = factory;
/** @type {myFunc} */
const fn = fact();
fn('world');
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `factory` returns a function that takes a string and returns nothing.

This can be expressed with a type expression using the `@return` tag:

```js
/** @return {function(string): void} */
function factory() {
  function myFunc(param) {
    console.log(`Hello ${param}!`);
  }
  return myFunc;
}
```

If `x` is assigned the result of `factory()`, your IDE should be able to work out its type:

[image]

Comment: My IDE PhpStorm cannot navigate to `myFunc` by 'Ctrl+Click' in this case :( My first goal is code navigation, not just return values definition with JSDoc. Thanks for your answer anyway :)